# Different bullet sizes in html without affecting line-height?

Tags: html, formatting

Please bear with me, I don't know much about html.

I'm trying to edit some html that has bullets of different sizes.  These bullets are inserted using &#8226 character.  I'm putting spans around them and changing their size by varying font-size, as below.

The problem I have is that the larger font-size bullet increases the font-height of the entire line, which (1) creates space between current line and previous line, and (2) puts bullet way above characters on current line.

What I want to do is simply make the bullet larger, but not change the line-height or the height of the bullet in relation to surrounding characters.  What is the proper way to do this?:

Some sample html text:

```
first line of text, which is fine
second line of text with bullet here: <span class="big-bullet">·</span> with text
coming after it.
```

and the css class:

```
.big-bullet{font-size:350%;}
```

EDIT:  Not sure of best way to do what I wanted, but I also discovered that the bullet in html text above is smaller than regular bullet.  It was in html generated by the TeX4ht converter, and I thought code in the LaTeX was &#8226. I have instead substituted the regular html bullet • `&bull;` in place of the small bullet and it's at least a little bigger.  Still doesn't scale nicely by changing font-size though. . .

```
first line of text, which is fine
second line of text with bullet here: <span class="big-bullet">&bull;</span> with text
coming after it.
```

and the css class:

```
.big-bullet{font-size:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix mite just be setting the [line height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp).

```
.big-bullet{
font-size:350%;
line-height:??px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's going to do it for me.  First, it seems to give me a fixed line height for that line (and the subsequent line) which won't change if user zooms in or out on the webpage.  Second, it doesn't change height of bullet in relation to other characters, bullet is so high it's up in position of an apostrophe.